# SLF4J ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, user-agent

I want to run UADetector in a Java servlet, but I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/uadetector/service/UADetectorServiceFactory
    test.doGet(test.java:158)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

However I have added the jar files to my library and I see them in the project folder (I use Eclipse).

This is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory;
import net.sf.uadetector.UserAgent;
import net.sf.uadetector.UserAgentStringParser;
import net.sf.uadetector.ReadableUserAgent;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class test
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // Get an UserAgentStringParser and analyze the requesting client
        UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
        ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));

        out.append("You're a <em>");
        out.append(agent.getName());
        out.append("</em> on <em>");
        out.append(agent.getOperatingSystem().getName());
        out.append("</em>!");
    }

}
```

Did anyone else have had this problem?

EDIT:
After also putting the jars in WEB-INF/lib folder the error has changed to:

```
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/uadetector/service/UADetectorServiceFactory
test.doGet(test.java:158)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
net.sf.uadetector.datareader.XmlDataReader.<clinit>(XmlDataReader.java:85)
net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory$ResourceModuleXmlDataStore.<clinit>(UADetectorServiceFactory.java:62)
net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory.<clinit>(UADetectorServiceFactory.java:92)
test.doGet(test.java:158)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

EDIT2:
It seems I need to be a bit more specific how I add the jar files.

I go to File -> properties -> java build path -> "Add External JARs"

This has worked for my other jars as well ( like mysql-connector-java)

EDIT 3:
So the classpath for compilation and runtime can be different. I have no idea which jars are neccesary for runtime and which only for compilation. So I copied all jars which are used also in the WEB-INF/lib folder. In the Deployment Assembly I have the following:

Source

- /src
- /WebContent

Deploy Path

- /WEB-INF/classes
- /

WEB-INF is located in WebContent so I think this should be correct.

However why is the class: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, missing?

Comment: your project > Properties > Deployment Assembly > in table you should have /WebContent

Comment: @ToKra I'm sorry but I don't understand what I need to do. /WebContent is already in the table, is it not?

Comment: Okay, another question: what SLF4J & Log4j (or LogBack) libs are you having in ./WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: I downloaded the slf4j-1.7.10.zip from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html, I unzipped it and placed the entire folder in the ./WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @ToKra , I think I understand what is going wrong. SLF4J is a dependency of UADetector. But I'm not adding the SLF4J correct. I took slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar out of the folder and placed it directly in the /WEB-INF/lib folder and then the message changed to another ClassNotFoundException. How can I add this dependency correctly?

Comment: You need SLF4J api JAR, then IMPL: either LOG4J, LOG4J2 or LOGBACK.

Comment: See my second answer bellow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70382/discussion-between-to-kra-and-user3605780).

Answer (score 1):

Where in your project did you add the libraries?  They need to be in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory to be deployed to the application server with your application and in the CLASSPATH at runtime.  Note that the runtime CLASSPATH can be very different from the CLASSPATH used for compiling.

---

---

> I go to File -> properties -> java build path -> "Add External JARs"

Don't do that.  That sets the CLASSPATH used to compile, but does not make the libraries available at runtime in your JavaEE container.  It is okay for Java SE projects where you are not working on a team (or everyone on the team has the same paths on their computer) but does not work well with Java EE.

Since, it appears, in your Deployment Assembly the directory in your project named "WebContent" becomes the root of the deployed JAR/WAR, copy the library jar files to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`.  Then when your application is deployed it will contain the libraries and they will be in the location where the JavaEE specification requires them.

Comment: I tried copying them in the lib folder but I get a different error then. I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: I updated my answer with more specifics based on the additional information you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problems with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) missing JARs:
You need `SLF4J API` then `IMPL` which could be:

- [LOG4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)
- [LOG4J2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)
- [LOGBACK](http://logback.qos.ch/)

I was using in past LOGBACK because I liked its XML configuration. In our project we used LOG4J but later migrated to newest LOG4J2 which should have better performance than any other loggers.

In my project I have these JARS: (1st is only because of backward compatibility to LOG4J)
[image]

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Hi, I went in the chat but got now response. So this is what I did:
I downloaded LOG4J2, and placed all jars in the lib folder but this gave a stackoverflow error

Comment: I saw this is mostly caused by wrong recursions. So I created a new project. I only added log4j-api-2.1.jar,log4j-core-2.1.jar,log4j-impl-2.1.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
then I have tomcat 8.0 library and jdk1.8.0_31 library
and in the tomcat lib folder I have uadetector-core-0.9.22.jar, uadetector-json-0.1.22.jar, uadetector-resources-2014.10-sources.jar and uadetector-resources-2014.10.jar
Now I'm getting the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory